# arithmetic sequence $8n+1$ and the collatz conjecture

Tags: number-theory, collatz-conjecture

Is it a known result that if for all $n$ the collatz sequence of $8n+1$ lead to $1$, all natural numbers will?

Comment: If I may think out loud for a minute: $8n + 1$ leads to $24n + 4$, then $12n + 2$, $6n + 1$, $18n + 4$, $9n + 2$; that's a bifurcation right there which depends on the parity of $n$.

If $n$ is odd, then the next step is $27n + 7$, which is even, and the next step is $\frac{27n}{2} + \frac{7}{2}$.

But if $n$ is even, the next step after $9n + 2$ is $\frac{9n}{2} + 1$...

Comment: @James47 You wouldn't need to show that all 8n+1 reach one to answer OP's question though

Comment: I doubt that there is such a connection. Why would there be such a connection? Consider for example Fermat's conjecture. Prior to the Wiles proof, people said that if you can prove it for prime exponents you've proven it for all exponents. Turns out instead you had to prove all semi-stable elliptic curves over $\mathbb{Q}$ have to be modular. Who knew, besides a few experts?

Comment: You're right, @DennisMeng. But frankly, and speaking only for myself, the question of $8n + 1$ is more interesting than any connection that may or may not pan out in an actual proof of the conjecture, as in the example Robert gives with Fermat's conjecture.

Comment: @RobertSoupe, I'm not sure what point your trying to make, the proof of Fermat's last theorem is still "one prime at a time". Suppose you have a prime $\ell$ and $a^\ell + b^\ell = c^\ell$. From this information you construct the Frey curve, and then apply modularity to it and eventually reach a contradiction. My point is, the proof still works by proving it only for prime exponents.

Comment: @DylanYott Yeah, that's how it turned out. My point was about how they thought it was going to be solved before knowing about Frey curves and modular elliptics, etc. The proof of the Collatz conjecture will most likely make a connection between things we can't currently see as having anything to do with each other.

Answer (score 1):

A quick sketch to show that `8*n+1` occurs in any trajectory:

Write any positive integer `x` as `m*2^(v+1) + 2^v - 1`, or `(m,v)`.

Examples: `1 = (0,1)`; `6 = (3,0)`; `27 = (3,2)`.

For `v>=1`, `succ((m,v)) = (3*m+1,v-1)`. This is doing the same as `(3*x+1)/2`.

Example partial trajectory: `(3,2) -> (10,1) -> (31,0)`, which represents `27 -> 41 -> 62`.

As now `v==0`, `62 -> 31 = (0,5)`, and continue.

At each `v==1` the reached value is congruent to `1 (mod 4)`, so this already means that `4*n+1` is in any trajectory.

For `even n` that is also congruent to `1 (mod 8)`.

For `odd n`, because `succ(4*n+1) = (3*(4*n+1)+1)/2/2 = 3*n+1 = succ(n)`, repeat if feasible, then the final `n` is not congruent to `1 (mod 4)`, and can be used as `x`, from the start. Repeat until an `8*n+1` is reached. As is essential to Collatz, there is no limit to the number of steps needed, as one can always construct a case with more steps.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

In https://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/38-1/andaloro.pdf (Andaloro, 1998), which is mentioned in https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0608208.pdf (Lagarias, 2012) as "(Andaloro, 2000)", there are proofs for both `1 mod 8` and `1 mod 16` to be "sufficient".

Answer (score 0):

As Robert Soupe says, why would a result binding on 8n+1 prove the conjecture?

Is there a missing line of background that shows where that expression comes from? Why not 16n+1 or something else?

Checking whether n can coexist in one sequence with 4n+1 (same n) is a bit more interesting because it would be essential for a loop.